# Does uncommon mean not shared?

Tags: word-meaning, word-request

According to [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/common), common has a meaning of "belonging equally to, or shared alike by, two or more or all in question". I want the opposite of this meaning, i.e., not shared. However, I found nowhere in the dictionaries that uncommon has such a meaning. Can it be used for such a purpose? If not, what else can be used?

Comment: It depends on ***what*** is not being shared, what is not being held or owned or had in common. Uncommon means: not usual, and it is not the antonym of common.  In short, it depends on your context.

Comment: I want an antonym of common. What else should I use?

Comment: There are a few, some that you'd use in different situations.  Check out the definitions of [private](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/private), [proprietary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proprietary), and [exclusive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exclusive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use *uncommon* in the way you want—although the logic is sound. The problem is that the word *common* has multiple meanings. But its reverse does not include the reverse of all of those meanings.

You can say:

> They stood on common [shared] ground.

But you cannot say:

> They stood on uncommon [unequally divided] ground.

At least, not without the meaning of *uncommon* changing to *rare*.

The word **lopsided** is similar to the idea of something that is unequally divided, except that its meaning is actually closer to *asymmetrical*, and has more relevance to a single item's physical appearance than to the unequal division of things between people or places.

I've already used the phrase **unequally divided** twice. I can't think of a single word that's at least as appropriate.